# regular expression to get sub string via php

Tags: php, regex, substring

How can I use a regular expression in the `substr()` PHP function to get a substring matched by a pattern?

Edited:

example:

```
$name = 'hello [*kitty*],how good is today';
```

I want to get what is between [*....*] placeholder.

Comment: Could you please provide a sample input - output? It's hard to tell what you want to achieve, I doubt `sub_str` function is needed if you want to match a part of a string. `preg_match `would be enough.

Comment: Please give your problem!! We give you solution

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: How to find the beginning and end of a substring in a string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3706175/php-how-to-find-the-beginning-and-end-of-a-substring-in-a-string)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

`substr()` only matches whole strings. You are looking for [`preg_match()`](http://php.net/preg_match).

**Update**:

```
$name = 'hello [*kitty*],how good is today';
preg_match( '/\[(.*?)\]/', $name, $match );
var_dump( $match );
```

You can find the name in `$match[1]`. I suggest you read up on regular expressions to understand `preg_match()`.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
$matches = array();
preg_match("/\[([^]]*)\]/", 'hello [*kitty*],how good is today', $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Oops, fixed it now :)

Comment: Try again, I fixed the regexp