# Separate a value from string php?

Tags: php, regex

How can i get the certain value from the url using php?

```
$orginal=http://wwww.flickr.com/photos/username/1125323/in/photostream/lightbox/";
```

i want 1125323 from this url?

Comment: Is the URL format always the same? Is the number always after the 3rd `/` in the URI? http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Comment: this might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4991554/regular-expression-to-get-sub-string-via-php

Comment: You're also missing your first quotation mark.

Comment: Pleeeeeeeeeease do some research before asking :( This can be done using preg_match(), preg_split(), explode(), strpos() & substr() ....

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to extract img src, title and alt from html using php?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/138313/how-to-extract-img-src-title-and-alt-from-html-using-php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use following code:

```
<?php
    $orginal="http://wwww.flickr.com/photos/username/1125323/in/photostream/lightbox/";
    $url_data = explode("/",$orginal);
    $id = $url_data[5];
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

use `.*?(\d+)` -> `\1` as a regex.

```
$out = preg_replace('/.*?(\d+)/','$1', $url);
```

Tip: use [Txt2re](http://txt2re.com/) if you want to do this again.

Comment: Looks like a username, and that might not always be only numbers.