# How do i get the page numbers from the example (with PHP)

Tags: php, regex

I have different versions of filenames.

How can i get `123.pdf`, `124.pdf` and `125.pdf` from it?
The length of filenames can vary, `14-5678` is not relevant for this time and should be ignored.

- `14-5678_jobname_0123_.p1.PDF`
- `14-5678_jobname_0123_.p2.PDF`
- `14-5678_jobname_0125_.p1.PDF`
- `Weired_filename_0123_bla_14-5678_jobname.p1.PDF`
- `Weired_filename_0123_bla_14-5678_jobname.p2.PDF`
- `Weired_filename_0125_bla_14-5678_jobname.p1.PDF`
- `14-5678_jobname_0123.p1.PDF`
- `14-5678_jobname_0123.p2.PDF`
- `14-5678_jobname_0125.p1.PDF`
- `0123_14-5678_jobname.p1.PDF`
- `0123_14-5678_jobname.p2.PDF`
- `0125_14-5678_jobname.p1.PDF`
- `jobname_0123_14-5678.p1.PDF`
- `jobname_0123_14-5678.p2.PDF`
- `jobname_0125_14-5678.p1.PDF`

Tried for hours with regexp testers, I'm now totally stuck. Would love some PHP-Code which can do this job.

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4991554/regular-expression-to-get-sub-string-via-php

Comment: `code` /_\d{4}_/g `code` is the best i got so far get a part. No PHP code so far, still trying to figure out how i can combine "or" for the case the page number has no leading "_". Really sorry, i don't have more.

Comment: Like this? http://regex101.com/r/vB5fA5/2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to match a series of four numbers that are not preceded by a dash:

```
/[^-](\d{4})/
```

Decomposing the regex:

- `[^-]`: not a dash
- `\d{4}`: four digits
- `(\d{4})`: capture the digits

You can then add `.pdf` to get your file name.

Example with `preg_replace` and the file names you've given above in an array:

```
foreach ($files as $f) {
    echo "$f => " . preg_replace("/.*?[^-]*(\d{4}).+/", "$1.pdf", $f) . PHP_EOL;
}
```

ETA: if you want to factor in the page number, you could use this code:

```
foreach ($files as $f) {
    # this saves the four digits of the PDF name, and the number in p1/p2
    preg_match("/.*?[^-]*(\d{4}).*?p(\d+)\.pdf/i", $f, $matches);
    # if the number (from p1/p2) is greater than 1, add it to the PDF name number
    if ($matches[2] > 1) {
        $matches[1] += $matches[2] - 1;
    }
    # format the pdf name to be four digits long, with zero padding for shorter names
    echo "$f => " . sprintf('%04d.pdf',  $matches[1]) . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Output:

```
14-5678_jobname_0123_.p1.PDF => 0123.pdf
14-5678_jobname_0123_.p2.PDF => 0124.pdf
14-5678_jobname_0125_.p1.PDF => 0125.pdf
Weired_filename_0123_bla_14-5678_jobname.p1.PDF => 0123.pdf
Weired_filename_0123_bla_14-5678_jobname.p2.PDF => 0124.pdf
Weired_filename_0125_bla_14-5678_jobname.p1.PDF => 0125.pdf
14-5678_jobname_0123.p1.PDF => 0123.pdf
14-5678_jobname_0123.p2.PDF => 0124.pdf
14-5678_jobname_0125.p1.PDF => 0125.pdf
0123_14-5678_jobname.p1.PDF => 0123.pdf
0123_14-5678_jobname.p2.PDF => 0124.pdf
0125_14-5678_jobname.p1.PDF => 0125.pdf
jobname_0123_14-5678.p1.PDF => 0123.pdf
jobname_0123_14-5678.p2.PDF => 0124.pdf
jobname_0125_14-5678.p1.PDF => 0125.pdf
```

Comment: @alien Thank you so much, this is almost perfect. I honestly don't understand **anything** what the regex does, my brain fries on this. But in your example `0123.pdf` exists two times. The originals are often cutted 2-pages-PDFs. How do i get rid off `14-5678_jobname_0123_.p2.PDF` as a) ignore it, don't use it, do not match on this or b) the perfect solution: get it calculated to the page 124 that it is?

Comment: Not sure if it must, but doesn't work with: `$f = "1234-5678_jobname_0123_.p1.PDF";`

Comment: @M42: That must not work. The 14 is for the year 2014. So 14-5678 would be Job No. 5678 in 2014.

Comment: @Steve I've added in code that will increase the page number

Comment: @alien Thanks a lot again! I still don't get the regex, but you've helped me a lot.

Comment: @Steve I'm sorry, I forgot to reply yesterday--regex101.com has a great decoder if you're puzzled by the regex; [here's a link to the regex I used](http://regex101.com/r/yF8zU1/1) -- you can mouse over the different pieces of the regex and see what each bit means.

Comment: @alien: Thanks for the link. Now that it's there I understand it, but creating this myself from nothing... i still don't see that. I'd need much more time and practise than i have for this to really understand it.