# How to get a substring throughout document knowing the markers?

Tags: php, regex, string

I know the strings in need lie between

"=t\">"   and     ")"

but this occurs several times in a body of text.

How can I extract between multiple instances of this occurence?

I have tried Explode, a variety of functions, preg_split, for 6 hours
and only getting wrong results - Is it even possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: How to find the beginning and end of a substring in a string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3706175/php-how-to-find-the-beginning-and-end-of-a-substring-in-a-string)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your delimiters are `=t\">` and `)`.

```
preg_match_all('/=t\\">([.\n]+?)\)/', $str, $matches);

var_dump($matches);
```

It sounds like you are trying to parse some HTML. Have you considered DOMDocument?

Comment: i can't get it to work - I think the back and forward slashes are an issue the delimiters are actually =t"\> and   </a>)</font>

Comment: i guess the question is how do I code "/" in a string for preg_match_all

Comment: @Graham You escape it with a backslash (you only need to if using `/` as the regex delimiters).

Comment: warning: preg_match_all() [function.preg-match-all]: Compilation failed: unmatched parentheses at offset 18 in /                                                          preg_match_all('#=t\\>([.\n]+?)\</a>)</font>#', $s, $matches);
won't seem to work any which way i try

Comment: @Graham You do have an unmatched parenthesis at the end.

Comment: i couldn't tell you where it was. the only parenthesis i see are the one which is part of the delimiter, and the one at the very end of the function.

Comment: I placed a \ in front of the parenthesis which is part of the 2nd delimiter, it worked without error. Yet didn't yield the result it should have. Perhaps I make these strings into variables? Be much easier. man. preg_match is a primadonna