# PHP Variable " How to copy specific data from variable"

Tags: php, string, variables

if i have stated data in my php variable, how i can copy from the santance from "any" to "Would".

**Data Example:**

If you have **any questions about Macmillan we would** love to hear from you.

Thanks for the help.

Kind Regards,
Reel.

Comment: A combination of `substr()` or `strpos()` or regular expressions. Your question is too specific to be answered unless you literally want a phrase between those two exact words.

Comment: Are the contents between `any` and `would` subject to change, or always the same?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to find the beginning and end of a substring in a string?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3706175/), [Extracting a substring that is wrapped by some characters](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10720531/), [How to get a substring throughout document knowing the markers?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5739973/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
$string = 'If you have any questions about Macmillan we would love to hear from you.';

preg_match('/( any )(.*?)( would )/', $string, $matches);

echo $matches[0]; // any questions about Macmillan we would
```

**EDIT 1**

To match more than one result, if exists:

```
preg_match_all('/( any )(.*?)( would )/', $string, $matches); 

foreach($matches[0] as $value)
    echo 'Found: ' . $value . '<br />';
```

Comment: if we have more than one results how we could do that?

Comment: @Reel, In this case you should use [preg_match_all()](http://br.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.preg-match-all.php) instead of [preg_math()](http://br.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.preg-match.php). I've made a new edit, you can see an example.

Comment: @Reel, I am glad to help you! Please don't forget to mark the best answer if your question was solved.

Answer (score 1):

Using [`preg_match()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php):

```
$somestr = 'If you have any questions about Macmillan we would love to hear from you.';
if (preg_match('/(\bany\b.+?\bwould\b)/i', $somestr, $matches)) {
    echo $matches[0];
}
```