# Extracting a substring that is wrapped by some characters

Tags: php, javascript, regex

What is **best practice** to select content between a pair of delimiter using regular expression excluding the delimiters in **PHP** and **JS**?

```
aassssd [dddd] fff ffff (delimiter=[..])   output -> dddd
aassssd QddddQ fff ffff (delimiter=Q)      output -> dddd
aassssd RddddQ fff ffff (delimiters=R...Q) output -> dddd
aassssd "dddd" fff ffff (delimiter=")      output -> dddd
```

Concern is about excluding delimiters, selecting whole is relatively easy:

```
/\"[^"]\"/ //for  line four
```

It's preferable that solution return a scaler. An ideal answer only uses RegEx, that can be tested in http://regexpal.com/

Comment: Are you sure you want to do that using a RegExp? Regular expression are slow.

Comment: Regex is slow? Compared to what?

Comment: How do you determine the delimeter? Is it always the literal "aassssd " followed by a delimiter, the text, a delimiter and the rest of the string, or will it be one of a specified set? Or is it some other pattern?

Comment: @kalisjoshua To `indexOf`, for example. Not to mention that they're way more obscure.

Comment: @IBBoard The question is general

Comment: Sorry for the divergence but do you have examples or perfs of indexOf outperforming regular expressions? I am not trying to be a troll I actually would like to see tests proving one way or another. If not I might make some of my own.

Comment: @Reza So basically the question is "how do you use a regex to get a substring?"?

Comment: @IBBoard Please note to question. it's clear

Comment: @IBBoard I'm guessing it's more of a comparison of ways to do it, such as negated character class vs lookahead vs lazy quantifier.

Comment: @kalisjoshua Regex is slow, compared to substr or other string manipulation functions.  `substr`, when it can be used, is orders of magnitude faster than the equivalent regular expression. This is trivial to benchmark.

Comment: Well, regex is for pattern matching not string manipulation. And, to be clear I come from a JavaScript background so I use regex all over the place, I don't know/use much PHP so I wont defend the performance there. @meager

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: How to find the beginning and end of a substring in a string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3706175/php-how-to-find-the-beginning-and-end-of-a-substring-in-a-string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
aassssd [dddd] fff ffff (delimiter=[..])   output -> dddd
```

RegEx for PHP:

```
(?<=\[).*?(?=\])
```

RegEx for JS (works in PHP too):

```
[^\[]*?(?=\])
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use the non-greedy `.*?` which captures everything upto the end delimiter :

```
$str = 'aassssd QddddQ fff ffff';
preg_match_all('/[Q](.*?)[Q]/', $str, $out, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
var_dump($out);
```

produces :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => QddddQ
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => dddd
        )

)
```

You would need to escape the `[` and `]` delimiters : `/[\[](.*?)[\]]/`

This uses a single capture group `(.*?)` so the output you need is in position 1 in the output array.

Comment: Thanks, I also tried "#(?<=Q)[^Q]*(?=Q)#s"?, but it did not act correctly, what is wrong about it?